# Retrive a specific record from mySQL and display it in html

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database filled with records and i want to retrieve data from it using php and display it in an html file. The problem is that i need to display a single row at a time in the html page by the specified client_id. Im new to php and mySQl, new also at stackoverflow, so please be understanding. Thank you all.

Here are two functions that i use to retrive data.

```
queries.php
//Get all clients from the db.
function get_all_clients() {
require (ROOT_PATH."inc/database.php");
try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY client_id ASC");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error Code: 1046";
    exit;
}
$clients = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $clients;
}

//Get single client from the db.

function get_client_single() {
  require (ROOT_PATH."inc/database.php");
  try{
      $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients
      WHERE client_id= ? ORDER BY client_id ASC");
      $results->bindParam("?", $client_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $results->execute();
  }catch(Exception $e){
     echo "ERRROR";
     exit;
  }
    $client = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The result that i should take should be something like:

```
index.php

<?php
require_once("inc/config.php");
include(ROOT_PATH . "inc/queries.php");
$allClients = get_all_clients();

$fName  = "John";
$lName  = "Pappas";
$gender = "Mr";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Blood Test Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test Form</h1>
<p>
    Dear<?php echo " "."$gender" ." "."$fName" ." "."$lName" ." "?      >.
</p>

</body>
```

Some Help on how can i make it dynamic by calling the function and display a specific record asked by the user. Thanks to everyone

Comment: how is the user specifying the client id? will it be in the querystring, or by submitting a form from another page?

Comment: It will be submitted by a form. But for now it is ok if i read it from a variable ex: $client_id = 1;

Comment: `function get_client_single() {` needs to take a paramter: `function get_client_single($client_id) {`. Then you need to call that function from your main page e.g. `$client = get_client_single($client_id);` . Then you can use the results on the page.

Comment: Thank you ADyson! I inserted the parameter in my function but this is where i stuck. I call my function but how can i display the single client?

Comment: as per the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php, you'll get an associative array back. I don't know what your field names are but you can do something like `$client["gender"]`, `$client["fName"]` etc to get each field.

Comment: Thank you ADyson!